# Como convertir un decimal a binario en python?

Tags: python

Se que se puede hacer con `bin(num)`, pero sale con "0b" al principio, quiero que salga sin eso, tambien probe con `int(num, 2)` pero me sale este error:

TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El metodo [string format](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) para formatear strings permite representar enteros en binario usando el type `b`:

```py
'{:b}'.format(100) # <-- '1100100'
```

Comment: También se pueden usar [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) apartir de la versión 3.6.x: `f'{100:b}' #1100100`

Answer (score 1):

Si solo te interesa quitar el "0b", puedes usar un slice del string que retorna `bin()`:

```
bin(100)[2:] #Mostraría 1100100
```

Saludos.